# Conservation of energy in the "ideal physics world"

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, singularities, constrained-dynamics

Let us assume we are in the textbook ideal physics world, without any friction.  Now, if I place a ball at the top of a parabola U and let it go under gravity, the ball should roll up and down forever because of conservation of energy.  But what happens if I place the ball at the top of an absolute value curve V.  Then, because of the cusp, what happens?  In real life, the ball would crash into the wall at the bottom and stop.  But this is the ideal physics world.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "ideal physics world". Physicists simplify problems to get approximate solutions that are easy to understand and apply to similar situations. We are not inventing impossible worlds.

Comment: @CuriousOne Then why do we teach our students this?

Comment: A good physics teacher will teach that "physics is the art of approximation". You take a real world situation and you grasp the most important aspects of it and then you model those aspects mathematically. You test that model and you identify where it fails. You develop hypotheses for why the model fails, then you refine the model. At no point does this iterative procedure lose track of the difference between reality and the model. This is how they teach physics at the university level. Unfortunately, some forget this and then "ideal" takes on a life of its own. It shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value curve isn't differentiable at $x=0$ so the gradient is not defined there. Since the gradient is undefined there is no way to use Newton's laws there and the motion of the particle is also undefined.

It's not unusual for situations like this to arise in physics. For example at the singularity in the centre of a black hole the equations of motion are also undefined. The same applies to the Big Bang - we can describe the spacetime geometry arbitrarily close to the Big Bang but not at the Big Bang itself.

Given that this is physics not mathematics our approach is generally to say that these are mathematical ideals that do not exist in the real world.